# Coffeescript convert Array to Dict where the dict will have multiple values

Tags: coffeescript

In coffeescript, I'm trying to convert an array of objects into a dict, where one of the values of the object is taken as the key and all of the objects in the array with that value and up as being in an array in the dict linked to that key.

I have tried the code suggested here but this results in maximum one object per key. https://coffeescript-cookbook.github.io/chapters/arrays/creating-a-dictionary-object-from-an-array

I couldn't find any other examples that don't just result in one value per key.

So, for example (expanding on the example linked above), I have an array

```
cats = [
  {
    name: "Bubbles"
    age: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Sparkle"
    favoriteFood: "tuna"
    age: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Felix"
    age: 2
  }
]
```

I want my result to be

```
catDict = {
    1: [
         {
           name: "Bubbles"
           age: 1
         }
       ]
    2: [

         {
           name: "Sparkle"
           favoriteFood: "tuna"
           age: 2
         },
         {
           name: "Felix"
           age: 2
         }
       ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
catDict = {}
(catDict[cat.age]?.push(cat) or catDict[cat.age] = [cat]) for cat in cats
```

I used the accessor variant of the existential operator `?.` to soak up null references. When a null reference is encountered the second half of the `or` kicks in to initialize the array.

It's shorter, but I'm not sure if it's more elegant...

Answer (score 0):

Classic, coming up with a solution immediately after I give up and post the question on StackOverflow, but here's my solution:

```
addCatToDict = (cat, dict) ->
    key = cat.age 
    if key of dict then dict[key].push(cat) 
    else dict[key] = [cat]

catDict = {}
for cat in cats
    addCatToDict(cat, catDict)
```

interested to see more elegant solutions